# Want to use Search (Filter) Dropdown instead of Html select

Tags: javascript, jsp

```
<html:select property="batchfilename" 
      onchange="setvalue('batchfilename',$(this).val());submitpage();">
<html:options name="statistics.batchfilename" />

</html:select>
```

want to use Search (Filter) Dropdown instead of html:select tag.
Thanks in advance

Comment: <html:select property="batchfilename"
                  onchange="setvalue('batchfilename',$(this).val());submitpage();">

                  <html:options name="statistics.batchfilename" />
       
          </html:select>

Comment: please explain more

Comment: i think you want something like this  http://www.lessanvaezi.com/filter-select-list-options/      or    http://phppot.com/demo/dropdown-with-search-using-jquery/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to take a look at this [link](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/). If you scroll down to section "Live Search", try the example. This dropdown list gives you the functionality to search through the list in real-time, very reliable I've used it in my private projects.

In order to make it work, you'll just have to insert the libraries needed, which can be found on that page too. Please mark this as answer if you believed this has helped you.